# python class attributes as standard input in a class method

Tags: python, oop

I don't seam to be able to do this but is would make sense that you could.
So mybe I just made a mistake.

```py
class Foobar:
  def __init__(self):
    self.myatr = 0 

  def add(self, someinput=self.myatr): # <-- someinput=self.myatr??? 
    return someinput += 1
```

but you get the error

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

But it would be logicl if the this was the way it worket

```py
f = Foobar()
f.add() # returns  1
f.add(1) # returns 2
```

Comment: Set it to `None` and check value is `None` in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance methods are functions bound to *class* attributes, defined when the class is defined, before any instance exists. Similarly, the default value is set once, at definition time, not on-demand when the method is called without an explicit argument.

As such, you need a *sentinel* (typically `None`) which signals that no argument was passed.

```
def add(self, someinput=None):
    if someinput is None:
        someinput = self.myatr
    return someinput + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Default arguments are evaluated at function definition. Moreover, the names of the arguments defined earlier (like `self` in your function) aren't available during function definition. So when you refer to `self.myattr`, there's no `self` yet.

For example, consider this function:

```
>>> def test(thing=print('hello')):
...  ...
... 
hello
>>>
```

The expression `print('hello')` was evaluated right when the function was defined, and it won't be re-evaluated when you call `test`.

Also, `return someinput += 1` is an error too because assignment is not an expression.

Furthermore, integers are always copied, so if you do this:

```
def test(x):
    x += 1
    return x

a = 6
test(a)
```

`a` will still be equal to six, since the call `test(a)` copied `a`.